# Understanding Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I learning javascript and trying to understand more about the language.
The main issue is the position of the initialization of the variable.
If I put it inside the function works fine but if it's out doesn't work at all, but the other variable named "marcaDeSkate" even thought it's out of the function works fine.

Here's the code I'm playing with:

```
<label name="marcasDeSkate">Marcas de Skate:</label>
<select id="marcasList" name="marcaList">
  <option value="Darkstar">Darkstar</option>
  <option value="Element">Element</option>
  <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="skatebrand" id="txtSkateBrand" />
<input type="button" value="Add Skate" id="btnAdd" />
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var marcaDeskate = document.getElementById("marcasList").value
var btnAdd = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
var txtSkate = document.getElementById("txtSkateBrand").value /* the variable I'm testing */
btnAdd.addEventListener("click", addSkate);
/*
function addSkate()
{

    alert(marcaDeskate + " " + txtSkate);
}
*/
function addSkate() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += marcaDeskate + " " + txtSkate + "<br/>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is you're setting `marcaDeskate` to the value of `marcasList` as soon as the page loads. If the user changes what's in `marcasList` then `marcaDeskate` isn't updated. You'll have to get the value every time you want to use it. Same with any other inputs.

Comment: It's because it has no value when it gets assigned. You have to check what the value is after you hit the button or else it's whatever it was when the page was created.

Comment: assign the var outside of the function equal to the element. On click, access the element's value, and then append the innerHTML of your target. You've got most of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to init the `txtSkate` variable inside the `addSkate` function. You are initializing the `txtSkate` variable before the user write the input value.

Try this:

```js
var marcaDeskate = document.getElementById("marcasList").value
var btnAdd = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
var txtSkate;

btnAdd.addEventListener("click", addSkate);

function addSkate() {
  txtSkate = document.getElementById("txtSkateBrand").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += marcaDeskate + " " + txtSkate + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<label name="marcasDeSkate">Marcas de Skate:</label>
<select id="marcasList" name="marcaList">
  <option value="Darkstar">Darkstar</option>
  <option value="Element">Element</option>
  <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="skatebrand" id="txtSkateBrand" />
<input type="button" value="Add Skate" id="btnAdd" />
<p id="demo"></p>
```